# Android widget onUpdate() issues

Tags: android, widget

I have a widget in my app and it gets screwed up (one of it's resources, a counter, has to be visible only if greater than 0 and it does not react anymore to a press) every time I install/remove/update a 3rd party app because the onUpdate() method probably gets called and the code I have written is not executed properly.

It is certain that the AppWidgetManager reacts to the following intents:

```
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED
```

But how can I make the widget not react to such intents, it is not even registered for them in the manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding those actions to the manifest .. and avoid reacting to them in the `onReceive` method, it's somehow trivial solution but it will do !

Comment: I think even this works sporadically: on new app installs it seemed to fix the issue, but when apps get updated, the forced screen refresh still screws up my widget.

Comment: I only cannot get it working on app update although I have in the onReceive handlers for: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED, android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED, android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried overriding the onReceive method and check for the intent? I have provided a quick example.

```
if(intent.getAction().compareTo("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED") != 0) { 
    //do something cool;
}
```

This should allow you to check the incoming intent and filter out what you don't want